# Using C++17 static inline members in embedded MSP432 application, program fails to launch as reset occurs

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, cortex-m4

I am unable to debug my embedded software since I started using static objects.

I do not think that there is much difference in memory allocation/initialization between the classic static variables and the inline static ones I am using, yet, I suspect there is a problem with the C runtime library startup lagging behind the watchdog timer when initializing considerable amount of data into the BSS.

[This](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau646f/slau646f.pdf) user manual seems to provide a solution (section 5.3), but inserting such an early-called function in my code did not produce any changes whatsoever:

```
static void __attribute__((naked, used, section(".crt_0015")))
disable_watchdog (void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;
}
```

Maybe the attributes syntax for g++ is slightly different than that of gcc?

Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Comment: Is your build compatible with the section mentioned?  That attribute specification will put the code into the ".crt_0015" section, but if there's nothing in the startup code to use it, you're out of luck.  You may want to try putting a breakpoint at the first instruction out of reset, and step through the code from there (disabling the watchdog as necessary).  If nothing else, this could tell you how your particular library code implements early start-up.

Comment: GioP, if I'm reading you correctly, you propose that a problem you are experiencing, prior to your modification, may be due to the watchdog timer firing before your code in main() gets a chance to disable the watchdog. You found an example in the manual showing you how to insert a bit of code that runs prior to any initializations and immediately after _Start. It compiles. But the problem persists. I'll suggest the obvious: your earlier problem was not as you suspected -- instead, it's due to something else, yet. You may yet have more work to do.

Comment: C or C++? C++ and static storage duration objects is a well-known bottleneck. It's not so much the bss initialization, but the disgusting call of all C++ constructors that the CRT has to do before launching main(). There are two sensible ways around the problem: either don't let PC programmers near your constructors or port the whole code to C.

Comment: @TimWescott I don't think I can debug CRT operations, but good point

Comment: @Lundin I think the problem here is exactly CRT operation, I did not consider the well-known [static-init-fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)

Comment: Why can't you debug the CRT? It's usually available source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be easily solved by creating a watchdog object (WDT) halting itself in the constructor, and instantiating it as the very first data structure to be built by the CRT.

To make sure of objects initialization order I rolled back to the C++11 approach, defining all global data members in a separate source file, preceded by the WDT, to take full control of the constructors sequence and avoid the static init order fiasco.